# Is Asset folder read-only?

Tags: android

How to write files inside Asset Folder?
It's read only or write?
If any example then please share me.
How to Secure Asset Folder?
**or whether we create userdefined foder 7 can access it for browsing like file:///android_assets/www....**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> No,You cannot write in asset Folder, its read only.

[Internal Storage in Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)

Comment: Is there any way to create usedefiined folder n access it in Android for loading html files,like we done as asset folder.

Answer (score 1):

As the Name says it is has a kind of Supporting files used in it.

Like .ttf file and all.

It is **Read Only**

Comment: ok,but i want to encrypt the content of html,js files in asset folder &copy into Storage then again Decrypted how is this achive? Any Solution???It is for to Secure code purpose only...