# How to load xml file to xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin, xamarin.android

i save the Xml file in Assets folder and set Build Action to Android Assets now when i try to save the changes to xml file it gives exception System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/Q317664.xml" is denied.i am not sure why this exception is occurring please help me

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using Android.Content.Res;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace App17 
{
[Activity(Label = "App17", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    int count = 1;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        var xml = XDocument.Load(Assets.Open("Q317664.xml"));
        var node = xml.Descendants("Book").FirstOrDefault(cd => cd.Attribute("Id").Value == "1");
        node.SetAttributeValue("ISBN", "new");
        xml.Save("Q317664.xml");
     //   Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);

       // button.Click += delegate { button.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count++); };
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Assets` directory in the application bundle is read-only, you cannot write to the `Q317664.xml` xml document that you open. This is the cause of the `System.UnauthorizedAccessException`.

If you want to modify something bundled in the assets directory, extract it to a writeable location and then operate on that copy:

```
string fileName = "Q317664.xml";
string filePath = Path.Combine (Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.ToString (), fileName);
// Check if your xml file has already been extracted.
if (!File.Exists(filePath))
{
    using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(Assets.Open(fileName)))
    {
        using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(dbPath, FileMode.Create)))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
            int len = 0;
            while ((len = br.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                bw.Write (buffer, 0, len);
            }
        }
    }
}

// Operate on the external file
var xml = XDocument.Load(filePath);
var node = xml.Descendants("Book").FirstOrDefault(cd => cd.Attribute("Id").Value == "1");
node.SetAttributeValue("ISBN", "new");
xml.Save("Q317664.xml");
```

See:

- [Is Asset folder read-only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562904/is-asset-folder-read-only)
- [How to write files to assets folder or raw folder in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3760626/how-to-write-files-to-assets-folder-or-raw-folder-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You need to Add the XML file to Assets folder in Xamarin Android project

Then you can load Xml into variable like this

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(Assets.Open("data.xml"));
```

Comment: I place the xml file in Assets folder now this error is occurring
 Error 1 Invalid resource directory name: "res assets". c:\users\asad\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\App17\App17\aapt.exe App17

Comment: Whats the name of the xml file?

Comment: i have solved the problem by setting build action to android Assets now when i try to save the XML file after changing the attribute value it gives exception System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/Q317664.xml" is denied.i am not not sure why this exception is occurring please help me

Comment: Please edit the question and add full source code.And which build action have you set ?